# SystemVerilog ring oscillator simulation with different delays

Tags: verilog, oscillator, system-verilog, testbench

I am currently encountering issues with my ring oscillator simulation in SystemVerilog, which I cannot explain.

Toolchain:

```
╰─○ iverilog -V
Icarus Verilog version 11.0 (stable) ()
╰─○ vvp -V
Icarus Verilog runtime version 11.0 (stable) ()
```

ring_oscillator.sv looks as follows:

```
module RING_OSCILLATOR #(
    parameter INVERTERS_PER_RING=3,
    parameter INVERTER_DELAY=1
) (
    input  logic en,
    output logic out
);

    initial begin
        assert( (INVERTERS_PER_RING >= 3) && (INVERTERS_PER_RING % 2 != 0) );
    end

    logic [INVERTERS_PER_RING-1:0] wires;
    assign out = wires[0];

    genvar i;
    generate
        for(i=0; i<INVERTERS_PER_RING; i=i+1) begin
            if (i == 0)
                not #(INVERTER_DELAY) (wires[i], en ? wires[INVERTERS_PER_RING-1] : 0);
            else
                not #(INVERTER_DELAY) (wires[i], wires[i-1]);
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

/*
For INVERTERS_PER_RING = 3:

wires[0] = en ? ~wires[2] : 0;
wires[1] = ~wires[0];
wires[2] = ~wires[1];
*/
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
`include "ring_oscillator.sv"

module RING_OSCILLATOR_TB();

    logic en1;
    wire out1;
    RING_OSCILLATOR ro1 (
        .en (en1),
        .out(out1)
    );
    defparam ro1.INVERTERS_PER_RING=3;
    defparam ro1.INVERTER_DELAY=1;

    initial begin

        $dumpfile("ring_oscillator_tb.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, RING_OSCILLATOR_TB);

        #0;
        en1 = 0;

        #10;
        en1 = 1;
    
        #300;
        $finish();
    end
    
endmodule
```

This simulation results in somewhat expected output as follows:
[image: Simulation with 1ns input-to-output delay for inverters]

But, when reaching a delay of 5ns per inverter, by setting:

```
defparam ro1.INVERTER_DELAY=5
```

the oscillator malfunctions, as follows:
[image: Simulation with 5ns input-to-output delay for inverters]

The well-defined areas all have a width of 10ns, whereas the undefined areas have a width of 5ns.
I'm new to SystemVerilog and hardware design in general.
I would really like to understand what is actually happening here and how this may be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this issue, you should look at the waveforms of the `wires` signal inside the `RING_OSCILLATOR` module as well.

`wires[0]` is the output of the first `not` gate.  At time=0, the input of that gate will be 0 since `en`=0, but it will take time for the 0 to propagate to the output.  When INVERTER_DELAY=1, it takes 1ns for `wires[0]` to transition from x to 0.  It takes 2ns for `wires[1]` to go from x to 0, and 3ns for `wires[2]` to go from x to 0.  So, after 3ns, all `wires` signals will be 0.  Since you wait until 10ns to enable the oscillator, all signals have had a chance to become known.

However, when INVERTER_DELAY=5, it takes each `not` gate 5ns to clear the x, for a total of 15ns.  But, you enable the oscillator at 10ns, which means all gates have not had a chance to clear the x's.

To fix it, you need to wait a little more time, like 20ns.  For example, change:

```
#10;
```

to:

```
#20;
```